# Is it possible to remove 'cystitis sand' from bladder via bladder instillation?

Tags: dogs, veterinarian, urination

I have a pomeranian male dog. Four days ago, he was diagnosed with cystitis (struvite crystals) and a bladder concrement. During these 4 days he has experienced 3 procedures of urinary catheterization. Yesterday and this morning he was able to pee without a catheter. But now he can't pee again. One vet has recommended a surgical operation. Another vet has said that if catheter is freely moving through penis then therapeutic procedures are possible. My question is: Is it possible to wash out all this 'cystitis sand and bacteria' from bladder via bladder instillation?

Comment: I voted to close the question. You need to go with the advice of veterinary specialists. Of course, you should try to avoid surgery if possible by following some other treatment, but if there is no alternative, then do what needs to be done. Just choose reliable doctors, and choose the path. Do not do anything by yourself, especially when even doctors have problems dealing with it. I wish you good luck and health and long life to your small friend.